# Access userctrol's datacontext does not work for me

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datacontext

In wpf mvvm mode, i have a usercontrol like this

```
<UserControl  MyControl>
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid
       ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}"         
       Visibility = "{Binding the usercontrol's datacontext.UserGrade}"
    />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my MainPageView I use it like this

```
<Window:MainPageView
   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:My.ViewModel"
   xmlns:userCtl="clr-namespace:My.Controls"
   <Window.DataContext>
     <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   <userCtl:MyControl>
     <userCtl:Mycontrol.DataContext>
        <vm:MyControlViewModel/>
     </userCtl:Mycontrol.DataContext>
   <userCtl:MyControl>
</Window:MainPageView>
```

Now here's the question, how can I access the MyUserControl's datacontext.UserVisiable, and binding to the MyUserControl's datagrid visibility? I tried to use {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}} but it did not work, or I didi it wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You want to access property of `Window`, but using `UserControl` type in `FindAncestor`... why?

Comment: it's all ok because my viewmodel has the same property in the baseviewmodel

Comment: You want to access  MyUserControl's datacontext.Visibility. Do you have Visibility property on MyControlViewModel?

Comment: yes i have a visibility property

Comment: FindAncestor sucks.  Just give the root a distinct name (a guid is even fine) and use ElementName=whatevs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
        <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}"    
                  Visibility = "{Binding DataContext.UserGrade, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Explanation: Using RelativeSource for the Binding Source, helps you navigate throw the visual tree, to the first ancestor of the current control, of the type specified (UserControl). It then uses the UserControl.DataContext.UserGrade as the binding property.

If the Usercontrol.DataContext is null, then the binding will not work. As specified in the question, userControl has a DataContext that contains that property.

Also, you could try setting the `AncestorType=location:MyControl`, in case UserControl is not enough. (location: is the namespace where your control is located)

Comment: Rather than posting just some code without comments, you should explain in your answer why it works and what are the issues you solved.